# Google maps unwanted white lines in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having a problem with the Google map API v3,  I have created a map with custom stylers, and on IE9(windows 7)  white horizontal lines appear, these lines do not appear in any other browser/OS combo.

Just wondered if anybody else has come across this problem before, and could give me any hints.

thanks.

Screenshot: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=kbeyqq&s=5

[image]

Comment: I got the same problem! It appeared in IE when there were 2 neighboring rectangles. I created them using exactly the same coordinates but IE displayed 1px space between them. I don't know why. Maybe some stupid rounding error?

Comment: Hi, @Lee Im having the same problem. IE is really making me sick. Is there any update about this issue??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Google:
"This is a browser bug related to user selectable zoom level."

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4120#makechanges

They provided no further information on why. Sounds like if you can deal with a set zoom level you won't run into the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old topic but I had a similar problem this afternoon. I managed to remove the lines by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>. Hope that helps.

Comment: yep, Ctrl+0 resets the zoom to default, so confirms the accepted answer. Setting the zoom level has always caused display problems in browsers, particularly IE. Frustrating that as a site designer you have no control at all over it.